# ExtDoc + @private Properties

Tags: extjs, documentation, annotations

I'm using ExtDoc [code.google.com/p/ext-doc/] to generate the Documentation associated to a Javascript Application.
The problem is that when I try to declare a Private Property, that Property will never appear in the generated documentation.

This is the used annotation

```
/**
* This is a Private Property
* @type String
* @property name
* @private
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

ExtDoc is outdated and no more maintained. Instead use [JSDuck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck), which is the new official docs generator of Ext JS.